# Show a selectbox with all registers that employee using or no associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, input, associations, rails-4-2-1

So, I have a model Refinancing belongs to employee and employee has many refinancings. This employee can have many register (but register is just a column). In view refinancing, how make for show a selectbox with all registers?
I tried

```
<%= f.association :register %>
```

but don't work. I need show all register that employee. What I do?

Comment: Did you added the gem simple_form_for ?

Comment: <%= simple_form_for(@refinanciamento) do |f| %>

  <%= f.association :register %>

Comment: I think if you did not change your schema table from last question you post, each employee can have only one register right? not many

Comment: @ZhiliangTakutoXing Hi! So, each employee can have only cpf, BUT can have many registers, register is a simple column, not a table.

Comment: so you used ActiveRecord Serialize? otherwise how can you save many registers in a string column?

Comment: By id, a employee id 1 has cpf 111111 and register 3333-33. other employee id 2 has cpf 111111 and register 4444-44. and other employ id 3 has cpf 111111 and register 5555-55. Undestand? Unfortunately, I can't create a table Register for this... =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you are using the wrong syntax, The simple_form have lots helper methods to populate the inputs...

```
f.association :company, label_method: :company_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: false
```

In the above code :company means, the association name not the column name, In list box we need to show a label and set the vale for submit.

The above syntax is pretty much clear that show the association and then label and value methods.

Hope that will clarify you. For more details please read the GitHub documents for the same.

Comment: Hey, I have other problem, how filter for cpf? I receive for params the cpf and I would show all register this cpf instead of register.all